# How to plot a lineplot with dots on specific points with specific colors and linetypes for each line using seaborn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd



 data_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0,14,28,42,56, 0,14,28,42,56],
                         'y': [0, 0.003, 0.006, 0.008, 0.001, 0*2, 0.003*2, 0.006*2, 0.008*2, 0.001*2],
                         'cat': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
                         'color': ['#B5D8F0','#B5D8F0','#B5D8F0','#B5D8F0','#B5D8F0','#247AB2','#247AB2','#247AB2','#247AB2','#247AB2'],
                         'point': [14,14,14,14,14,28,28,28,28,28],
                         'linestyles':['-','-','-','-','-','--','--','--','--','--']})
```

I would like to produce a lineplot with different `color` and `linestyles` per `cat`. But I would like to give the specific `color` and `linestyles` per `cat` as they are defined in the `dataframe`. Lastly I would like to mark the `point`s on each line with the same color.

I have only tried:

```
sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", hue="cat", data=data_tmp)
sns.scatterplot(x="point",y="y",hue="cat", data=data_tmp[data_tmp.point==data_tmp.x])
plt.show()
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I could do this. You need to use the `cat` column to control the different plot parameters (color, style, marker size), and then create mapping objects (here dicts) that tell which parameter value to use for each category. The color is easy. The linestyle is harder, because Seaborn only offers `dashes` as a configurable parameter, which needs to be given in the advanced Matplotlib format of `(segment, gap)`. The function [`matplotlib.lines._get_dash_pattern`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/lines.html) translates the string value (e.g. `--`) to this format, although the returned value needs to be handled with care. For the marker size, unfortunately `lineplot` does not offer the possibility to change the marker size with the category (even though you can change the marker style), so you need to use a `scatterplot` on top. The last bit is the legend, you probably want to disable it for the second plot, to avoid repeating it, but the problem is that the first legend will not have the markers in it. If that bothers you, you can still edit the legend manually. All in all, it could look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Converts a line style to a format acceptable by Seaborn
def get_dash_pattern(style):
    _, dash = mpl.lines._get_dash_pattern(style)
    return dash if dash else (None, None)

data_tmp = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [0,14,28,42,56, 0,14,28,42,56],
    'y': [0, 0.003, 0.006, 0.008, 0.001, 0*2, 0.003*2, 0.006*2, 0.008*2, 0.001*2],
    'cat': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
    'color': ['#B5D8F0','#B5D8F0','#B5D8F0','#B5D8F0','#B5D8F0',
              '#247AB2','#247AB2','#247AB2','#247AB2','#247AB2'],
    'point': [14,14,14,14,14,28,28,28,28,28],
    'linestyles':['-','-','-','-','-','--','--','--','--','--']})
# Extract plot features as dicts
feats = (data_tmp[['cat', 'color', 'linestyles', 'point']]
         .set_index('cat').drop_duplicates().to_dict())
palette, dashes, sizes = feats['color'], feats['linestyles'], feats['point']
# Convert line styles to dashes
dashes = {k: get_dash_pattern(v) for k, v in dashes.items()}
# Lines
lines = sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", hue="cat", style="cat", data=data_tmp,
                     palette=palette, dashes=dashes)
# Points
sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", hue="cat", size="cat", data=data_tmp,
                palette=palette, sizes=sizes, legend=False)
# Fix legend
for t, l in zip(lines.legend().get_texts(), lines.legend().get_lines()):
    l.set_marker('o')
    l.set_markersize(sizes.get(l.get_label(), 0) / t.get_fontsize())
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Final plot]

Comment: Maybe the way that I phrased the question was misleading. Regarding the points, I meant that I would like points where the x-axis is equal to the `point` variable in the dataset for each line. But still your answer helped me figure it out

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to use matplotlib directly, like

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0,14,28,42,56, 0,14,28,42,56],
                   'y': [0, 0.003, 0.006, 0.008, 0.001, 0*2, 0.003*2, 0.006*2, 0.008*2, 0.001*2],
                   'cat': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],})


d = {"A" : {"color": '#B5D8F0', "markersize":  5, "linestyle": "-"},
     "B" : {"color": '#247AB2', "markersize": 10, "linestyle": "--"}}

for n, grp in df.groupby("cat"):
    plt.plot(grp.x, grp.y, marker="o", label=n, **d[n])

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with the help of @jdehesa

I also put the legend outside of the plot here and some polishing to the labels

```
def get_dash_pattern(style):
    _, dash = mpl.lines._get_dash_pattern(style)
    return dash if dash else (None, None)

palette = dict(zip(data_tmp.cat, data_tmp.color))
dashes = dict(zip(data_tmp.cat, data_tmp.linestyles))
dashes = {k: get_dash_pattern(v) for k, v in dashes.items()}

ax = sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", hue="cat", data=data_tmp, palette=palette, style='cat',  dashes=dashes)
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="point", y="y", hue="cat", data=data_tmp[data_tmp.point == data_tmp.x], palette=palette,
                     legend=False)

ax.set_title('title')
ax.set_ylabel('y label')
ax.set_xlabel('x label')
ax.legend(loc=(1.04, 0))
plt.show()
```

[image]